# How to use hide/show elements on webflow html with responsive mobile view?

Tags: html, webflow

I have a webpage created by someone on flow for our company landing page.

**What I have currently -**

When clicking on color buttons, it auto scroll to section of the webpage that is linked with each button. (HTML DOM Element scrollIntoView)

E.g. when clicked on "paragraph5" button, it auto scrolls to Paragrah5 section of webpage.

[image: Desktop layout]

---

**But the issue is on mobile view, those buttons wouldn't rescale to fit the mobile layout.**

[image: Mobile layout]

---

**What I would like to achieve -**

I want the buttons to auto scale for mobile layout (responsive to device screen resolution), meaning it would fit all buttons to mobile screen.

I want to replace autoscroll to hide/show only the paragraphs linked to it (as shown in below). Also only allows to show one section at a time.

E.g.

- step1: Clicked on paragraph3 button will shows paragraph3.
- step2: Clicked on paragraph1 button will shows paragraph1 at previous
  paragraph3 shown location.

**Desktop View**

[image: Desktop View]

**Mobile View**

[image]

Comment: where is your html,css code? please share!